# Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in /home/william/public_html/forums/index.php on line 228

Tags: php, sql

Why won't this work? I keep getting that error.
    // Setup forum topics, post count and last post xxxxx

```
        $query = array(
            'SELECT'    => 't.subject',
            'FROM'      => 'topics AS t, pbb_forums AS f',
            'WHERE'     => 't.last_post_id = f.last_post_id');

        $result = $forum_db->query_build($query) or error(__FILE__, __LINE__);

        $forum_page['item_body']['info']['topics'] = '<li class="info-topics"><strong>'.forum_number_format($cur_forum['num_topics']).'</strong> <span class="label">'.(($cur_forum['num_topics'] == 1) ? $lang_index['topic'] : $lang_index['topics']).'</span></li>';
        $forum_page['item_body']['info']['posts'] = '<li class="info-posts"><strong>'.forum_number_format($cur_forum['num_posts']).'</strong> <span class="label">'.(($cur_forum['num_posts'] == 1) ? $lang_index['post'] : $lang_index['posts']).'</span></li>';

        if ($cur_forum['last_post'] != '')
            $forum_page['item_body']['info']['lastpost'] = '<li class="info-lastpost"><span class="label">'.$lang_index['Last post'].'</span> <strong><a href="'.forum_link($forum_url['post'], $cur_forum['last_post_id']).'">'.$result['subject'].'</a></strong> <cite>'.sprintf($lang_index['Last poster'], forum_htmlencode($cur_forum['last_poster'])).'</cite></li>';
        else
            $forum_page['item_body']['info']['lastpost'] = '<li class="info-lastpost"><strong>'.$lang_common['Never'].'</strong></li>';
```

Comment: Is that fluxBB? What do you get if you do print_r($result); after calling the build_query() method?

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to use a mysqli result (`$result`) as an array without calling `fetch_array` on it.

Whatever framework you're using will probably provide a wrapper for this.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function fetch_array()

I've added this line to it:

$result = $forum_db->query_build($query) or error(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  $result = fetch_array($result);

Comment: It won't be just "fetch_array" but what it is depends on what framework you're using

Answer (score 1):

Well, you seem to have "something" (maybe $result ?) as an object ; and you are using everything as arrays.

Maybe you have a way to fetch data as arrays, and not objects ?
(Might be a way with the class you are using ? )

Or, you need to access data as objects, and not arrays ; maybe $result->subject, and not $result['subject'] would do ?